# function year(date) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql corre bien, pero en postgres me marca error en YEAR(dias_festivos.fecha)='2000', dice:

> function year(date) does not exist

¿alguien sabe porqué?

Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT dias_festivos.id, dias_festivos.descripcion, IF(**YEAR(dias_festivos.fecha)='2000',** 
CONCAT_WS(' ', CONCAT_WS('/', LPAD(DAY(dias_festivos.fecha), 2, '0'), 
LPAD(MONTH(dias_festivos.fecha), 2, '0')),
'TODOS'), CONCAT_WS('/', LPAD(DAY(dias_festivos.fecha), 2, '0'), 
LPAD(MONTH(dias_festivos.fecha), 2, '0'), 
YEAR(dias_festivos.fecha))) AS fecha FROM dias_festivos WHERE dias_festivos.status = 1
```

Comment: Nunca asumas que porque algo funciona en una base de datos, que necesariamente va a funcionar en otro. Cada base de datos tiene su sabor particular de SQL, y siempre es necesario investigar en la documentación de la base de datos en particular para averiguar cuales funciones podemos usar.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql no tiene una función `YEAR`, lo puedes cambiar por:

- `EXTRACT (field FROM source)`

> La función `EXTRACT` recupera subcampos como el año u hora de los
>   valores de fecha / hora. `source` debe ser una expresión de valor de
>   tipo timestamp, time o interval. (Las expresiones de la fecha de tipo
>   se enviarán a la marca de tiempo y, por lo tanto, se pueden usar
>   también). `field` es un identificador o cadena que selecciona qué
>   campo extraer del valor de origen. La función `EXTRACT` devuelve
>   valores de tipo doble precisión.
>
> ... La función de `EXTRACT` está principalmente destinada al procesamiento computacional.
>
> <sub>[Documentación de Postgresql sobre `EXTRACT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html)</sub>

O bien puedes usar:

- `DATE_PART ('field', source)`

> La función `date_part` es el equivalente Ingres de `EXTRACT`, que es
>   la función tradicional estándar de SQL.
>
> Tenga en cuenta que aquí el parámetro de campo debe ser un valor de
>   cadena, no un nombre. Los nombres de campo válidos para `date_part`
>   son los mismos que para `extract`.
>
> <sub>[Documentación de Postgresl sobre `DATE_PART`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html)</sub>

---

### Ejemplo: <kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/VFZ64349)</kbd>

Apliquemos ambas funciones a un ejemplo de código, sobre una columna llamada `FECHA` la cual es del tipo `DATE`.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_FECHA (
   ID_TEST     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   FECHA       DATE               NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TEST_FECHA (FECHA) VALUES ('2017-12-16'), ('20041120');

SELECT  ID_TEST, 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  FECHA) CON_EXTRACT,  
        DATE_PART('YEAR', FECHA)  CON_DATEPART
FROM TEST_FECHA;
```

---

#### Resultado:

```
id_test    con_extract      con_datepart
1          2017             2017
2          2004             2004
```